# parse json rest response in java

Tags: java, json, neo4j

I am trying to parse json output from neo4j in java as:

```
Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("D:\\neo4j.json"));

JSONArray json = (JSONArray)  obj;

System.out.println(json.size());

for (int i = 0; i < json.size(); i++) {
    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) json.get(i);
    String data = (String);   
    jsonObject.get("outgoing_relationships");
    String name = (String) jsonObject.get("name");
    System.out.println(data);
    System.out.println(name);       
}
```

### Can somebody help me to get values inside "data" element:

I have json output from neo4j as follows:

```
[{
"outgoing_relationships": "http://host1.in:7474/db/data/node/133/relationships/out",
"data": {
    "MOTHERS_NAME": "PARVEEN BAGEM",
    "MOBILE_NO": "9211573758",
    "GENDER": "M",
    "name": "MOHD",
    "TEL_NO": "0120-",
    "PINCODE": "110001"
},
"traverse": "http://host1.in:7474/db/data/node/133/traverse/{returnType}",
"all_typed_relationships": "http://host1.in:7474/db/data/node/133/relationships/all/{-list|&|types}",
"property": "http://host1.in:7474/db/data/node/133/properties/{key}",
"self": "http://host1.in:7474/db/data/node/133",
"properties": "http://lhost1.in:7474/db/data/node/133/properties",
"outgoing_typed_relationships": "http://host1.in:7474/db/data/node/133/relationships/out/{-list|&|types}",
"incoming_relationships": "http://host1.in:7474/db/data/node/133/relationships/in",
"extensions": {

},
"create_relationship": "http://host1.in:7474/db/data/node/133/relationships",
"paged_traverse": "http://host1.in:7474/db/data/node/133/paged/traverse/{returnType}{?pageSize,leaseTime}",
"all_relationships": "http://host1.in:7474/db/data/node/133/relationships/all",
"incoming_typed_relationships": "http://host1.in:7474/db/data/node/133/relationships/in/{-list|&|types}"
}]
```

Regards,
Jayendra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try following way. Inside the for loop get the data node as JSONObject. From that data node you can extract every property. I just extracted mother name from data.

```
JSONObject data = (JSONObject) jsonObject.get("data");
final String motherName = (String) data.get("MOTHERS_NAME");
```

Answer (score 0):

What library are you using to parse JSON ? I'd recommend that you use [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-core)

For eg: To get the data you read from the file in a Map, you can write a method like this.

```
   @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
 public static Map toMap(Object object) throws JsonProcessingException{                   ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    return mapper.convertValue(object, Map.class);
}
```